# Is there an R function to read Company's names off Yahoo Finance

Tags: r, stock, quantmod, tidyquant

Curious if it is possible to input a list of company names like `c("Netflix", "Tesla", "Apple")` and it returns the associated Ticker names such as `c("NFLX", "TSLA", "AAPL")` which I can then input into a function I created which returns the current closing prices. I simply want to automate the manual lookup of each company on Yahoo Finance. Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Those are all S&P 500 companies so if that is sufficient then get the list from Wikipedia.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

stocks <- data.frame(Symbol = c("TSLA", "NFLX", "AAPL"))

u <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
html <- read_html(u)
tab <- html_table(html)[[1]]

stocks %>%
  left_join(tab, by = "Symbol") %>%
  select(Symbol, Security)
```

giving:

```
  Symbol Security
1   TSLA    Tesla
2   NFLX  Netflix
3   AAPL    Apple
```

**2)** Even easier is to use the csv file at the url below giving the same result except for the second column name which is called Name rather than Security.

```
library(dplyr)

stocks <- data.frame(Symbol = c("TSLA", "NFLX", "AAPL"))

u2 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/s-and-p-500-companies/master/data/constituents.csv"
tab2 <- read.csv(u2)
stocks %>%
  left_join(tab2, by = "Symbol") %>%
  select(Symbol, Name)
```

Comment: Outstanding answer!